# Getting first file in a list of files into the first folder of a list of folders

Tags: r, list, file, directory, copy-paste

say I´ve got the following files:

```
File1.dat
File2.dat
File3.dat
File4.dat
.
.
.
File50.dat
```

and the following directories:

```
M1_Para1_Stand1
M1_Para1_Stand2
M1_Para1_Stand3
M1_Para2_Stand1
.
.
.
M2_Para6_Stand3
```

Now I would like to get `File1` into `M1_Para1_Stand1`, `File2` into `M1_Para1_Stand2`, `File50` into `M2_Para6_Stand3` etc. so that it looks like this:

```
M1_Para1_Stand1/File1.dat
M1_Para1_Stand2/File2.dat
M1_Para1_Stand3/File3.dat
M1_Para2_Stand1/File4.dat
.
.
.
M2_Para6_Stand3/File50.dat
```

Is there a way to do this via lists? 
Currently I am working with file.copy but thats kind of annoying...

Thanks for the replies

Comment: Sort files, folders and then move/copy `file[i]` into `folder[i]` ?

Comment: Problem is, that the Files and the folders are not named like in the example and it is not possible to sort the folders; Essentially I would like to get the first file in my directory in the first folder in my directory. If I would work with list.files/list.dirs it would mean, that the first file in my list.files gets into the first folder of my list.dirs

Comment: In that case, we would need to know how to map a file to a folder.  What are the naming conventions for each?

Comment: Do you want to write the files in the folders as `.csv` or something similar?

Comment: The files are .dat files.

Comment: edited first post; maybe its clearer now

Comment: Still makes no sense. There is no such a thing as "first file in my directory". Being _first_ implies some ordering, and you haven't specified that. Ordered by what? Name, date/time, size, etc.

Comment: I want the follwing done, without copy/paste the file.copy command 50 times...`file.copy("./File[1].dat", "./M1_Para1_Stand1", overwrite = FALSE)
file.copy("./File[2].dat", "./M1_Para1_Stand2", overwrite = FALSE)
file.copy("./File[3].dat", "./M1_Para1_Stand3", overwrite = FALSE)
file.copy("./File[4].dat", "./M1_Para2_Stand1", overwrite = FALSE)
...
file.copy("./File[50].dat", "./M2_Para6_Stand3", overwrite = FALSE)`

Comment: The folders and files are ordered by name...Sorry I was not thinking straight^^

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure if this is what you want but maybe it helps:

```
##Dummy Data##
x <- data.frame(a=1:5,b=5:1)
files <- do.call(list, replicate(5,x,simplify=FALSE))

##Create Folders##
folders <- paste0("Your_Path/folder_",1:5,"/")
lapply(seq_along(folders), function(x) dir.create(folders[x]))

##Write Data##
lapply(seq_along(files),function(x) write.table(files[[x]],paste0(folders[x],"file",x,".dat")))
```

Comment: hm, thats not really what I want because I only need to copy-paste my files into existing directories; but thanks!

Comment: @AndySOWI you could probably just use `file.copy` as a function within `lapply`.